# Why are collections of all etale-maps sets?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{S} = (E,p,X)$ and $\mathbb{S'} = (E',p,X)$ be etale-sheaves over
a topological space $X$.
We write ${\rm Hom}_{et}(\mathbb{S},\mathbb{S'})$ for the set of all etale-maps between  $\mathbb{S}$ and $\mathbb{S'}$.
But why should ${\rm Hom}_{et}(\mathbb{S},\mathbb{S'})$ be a set?

Comment: Aren't they defined by an honest function $E\to E'$?

Comment: LaTeX/MathJax tip: Enclose the entirety of a formula in \$\$, not each individual symbol.

Comment: @CaptainLama oh you're right. Haha what a silly question...

Comment: @C-RAM Thank you very much.